# Auto width on tables

Tags: html, css

A html table cols and rows are generated dynamically,

i.e, for the first instance it could be two rows and there columns.
and next time it could be two rows and 10 columns

My question is how to adjust the with automatically of the table so that the table always appears 100% in the page adjusting the coulmn size and row size

```
    <table>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>

    <table>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
     <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
  </table>
```

Thanks..

Comment: regardless of the correct answer though, the content of each TD can alter the size of the table for example, if a large image is placed in a td it can skew the size of the column. how should that be handled?

Answer (score 8):

Using CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
table { width: 100%; }
</style>
<table>
...
</table>
```

or using a CSS inline style:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
...
</table>
```

or using old school HTML:

```
<table width="100%">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put

width="100%"

In your table tag -- it will always be 100% width. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Why not? I would disagree -- and while I don't use tables frequently, I have never run into a problem using that nor have I seen it stayed that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: for once, inline styles are bad practice because they don't separate content from design. Here are some other reasons: http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/a/aa073106.htm

Comment: @vitorbal -- I didn't say anything about inline styles. It's an HTML property.

@Hulk: Yes, it would get automatically adjusted to fit, unless you gave percentage values to the width of your td's.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a css file in which you could write

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or you can prepend following lines in your html file

```
<style type="text/css">
  table { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
</style>
```

Comment: @Asaph -- Thanks for the hint. It's so early in the morning. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best I know so far, is this:

```
.my-table-class {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   width: 100%;
}
```

If you don't use `box-sizing: border-box;`, you will get bad results as soon as your table has paddings and borders. Using `width: 100%;` is not enough.

Hint: the same for an element with `display: table;`.